# nginx location new location redirection cycle

Tags: nginx

I moved a bunch of images on my site from `/images` to `/images/categories`.  I want the old URLs to still serve up the assets from the old location without duplicating them because I have 3rd parties that reference those URLs.  I attempted this with a location/try_files block:

```
location /images {
    try_files /images/categories/$uri $uri;
}
```

The problem is that then I get:

> rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/images/categories/myimage.png", client: 172.27.0.1, server: app, request: "GET /images/categories/myimage.png HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer:

How can I prevent the infinite loop here?

Comment: Add `=404` to the end of the `try_files` statement to prevent a loop. But your first term looks for files in `/images/categories/images/`.

Comment: When I do that, linking directly to the `/images/categories/my-image.jpg` or `/images/my-image.jpg` shows a 404 for an image that actually exists.  I'm so confused.

Comment: Have you set a value for `root` in the block surrounding `location /images`?

Comment: Yes, `root /var/www/html/public;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is that urls in `/images/categories` also match that `/images` location block. So you need to match for `/images/categories` first. Here's one way of doing that.

```
location ~ ^/images/categories/(.*) {
    try_files /images/categories/$1 =404;
}
location ~ ^/images/(.*) {
    try_files /images/$1 /images/categories/$1 =404;
}
```

Comment: That's a big step in the right direction.  Though if I'm not mistaken, the 2nd statement there says to look in `/images/categories` and 404 if it's not there?   In that case I'd want it to try `/images/categories` and then try `/images` and then 404.  The first block works as I want it to, the second one is showing a 404 when the asset does exist in `/images/`

Comment: Oh right, there are also files like /images/x which are *not* in /images/categories/x. I've updated the second location block to reflect that.

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Note that according to http://nginx.org/r/try_files, the final parameter is actually treated not as a `file`, but as a `uri`, resulting in an internal redirect within nginx, and hence the infinite loop condition as you report.

The correct way may be to use http://nginx.org/r/alias, as has been pointed out; else, you probably want to trail your `try_files` with a `=code` specification, to make sure that no redirection cycle gets to take place.

---

I.e., this will get rid of the `internal redirection cycle` error:

```
location /images {
    try_files /images/categories/$uri $uri =410;
}
```

---

However, do you really have the `/images/` part twice as part of your URL scheme, as in, `/images/categories/images/myimage.png` on the filesystem?  If not, then the correct solution may then be:

```
location /images/ {
    alias /var/www/html/public/images/categories/;
}
location /images/categories/ {
    root /var/www/html/public;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive might be perfect to meet your requirement.

```
location /images {
    alias /var/www/html/public/images/categories;
}
```